# Sensitivity Analysis for Raw Model Output or Model Predictions?

Tags: causality, marginal-effect, sensitivity-analysis

For a variety of reasons, many researchers have suggested that, for attempting to make causal inferences with non-linear statistical models, one should generally avoid endowing a causal interpretation to raw model output ([Mood 2009](https://www.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.341161.1501927873!/menu/standard/file/Eur%20Sociol%20Rev-2010-Mood-67-82%20(1).pdf), [Daniel et al. 2020](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/bimj.201900297), [Norton et al. 2019](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/2728169), [Long and Mustillo 2018](https://jslsoc.sitehost.iu.edu/stata/groupsbrm/2018-07-13%20package/long-mustillo-groups-2018-07-13.pdf)). Instead, model predictions can be used to evaluate the causal effect (assuming identifying assumptions hold) of a given treatment.

One popular strategy to obtain model predictions is the estimation of marginal effects. However, even following the estimation of marginal effects, an estimated marginal effect from an observational study is, by itself, not indicative of a causal relationship. The primary culprit generating suspicion is the potential for unadjusted confounding biasing a marginal effect estimate.

As a result, a key tool to lend credibility or to cast further suspicion on a given estimate are sensitivity analyses. I am fairly familiar with the sensitivity analyses developed by [Cinelli et al. 2020](https://carloscinelli.com/files/Cinelli%20et%20al%20(2020)%20-%20sensemakr.pdf) and [McGowan 2022](https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.04495.pdf). However, these sensitivity analyses examine how much a given coefficient, ratio, etc. would shift under a set of assumptions. However, if I am not interested in the raw output of a model, how much should I care about the sensitivity of such a coefficient, ratio, etc. in the first place? Or is the sensitivity to the raw model output analogous to the sensitivity (sensitivity to unspecified confounding) of a model prediction such as an average marginal effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw model output", and if not that, what are you interested in?

Comment: @Scriddie By raw model output, I mean any coefficient, odds ratio, hazard ratio, etc. that the model naturally produces. The inclination is to interpret these outputs as marginal effects, but such interpretation, as I understand, is not appropriate outside of a linear model with only linear terms on the right-hand side. Using model predictions, such as with the {marginaleffects} package can allow the user to estimate the target estimand of interest. But the AME of X on Y, for example, may not be the coefficient for X. I'm interested in the AME, but existing SAs evaluate sensitivity of beta.

Comment: ah so you're looking for something like sensitivity analysis in the Cinelli style for a nonlinear causal effect or a nonlinear causal model in general?

Comment: @Scriddie Correct! Something that examines the sensitivity of an AME rather than just the reported coefficient. But, I'm also curious if the sensitivity of an AME is equivalent to the sensitivity of a coefficient, even if the coefficient itself is uninterpretable as a causal effect estimate.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any widely established practice in that direction, although I imagine there must be some research on it. The problem I see is that once you allow for non-linearity everywhere in the model, the sensitivity to confounding could be anything. One could probably assume Lipschitz-continuity with some constant... that might be an interesting idea but not sure what's been done in that direction. Perhaps it makes sense to look among the works that cite Cinelli et al. if you haven't already?

Comment: “How much should I care about A?” and “Is A analogous to B?” are not questions with good answers here.